# Ping: unknown host google.com on CentOS 7 in Virtual Box

Tags: centos, centos-7

I'm attempting to talk to the outside world (the internets) via CLI. I'm using CentOS 7 on Virtual Box and I can't get anything to work. I've modified just about every file on the system, restarted from scratch, etc. Please help.

Comment: Have you configured for network connection at all? For example, get NetworkManager started and configure the NIC with `nmcli` / `nmtui`?

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction on how to do that? Not a sysadmin, nor am I familiar with CentOS.

Comment: If you have no idea at all you better get a book...but well these two parts gives you a start to try things out randomly yourself: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Installing_NetworkManager.html#sec-The_NetworkManager_Daemon https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_Text_User_Interface_nmtui.html

Comment: I assume that you are able to browse from your host, but you are not able to get anything from the guest virtual machine? Can you update your question with the information what kind of network connection you have chosen for the VM (NAT, Bridged, Internal)?

Comment: @zina I'm using a bridged connection. I was able to get things up and running via `nmtui`; however, I can't access the actual server from my desktop.

Comment: could you please explain what you mean with "I can't access the actual server from my desktop". Desktop as in host of VM? Server as in Centos? Access as in ssh?